# Multiselection in vb.net ListBox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a list of student names in a listBox,(studentList)I click on a name in the box and get all the students details up ie name, course, subject etc.The code then gets the details from the database(in my case it's access) then displays it in a datagridview.
The code works fine if I just select one item from one(or all)List Boxes.My question is, can I select more than one item per LitsBox.I know I can use SelectedMode property to allow the highlighting but that wont draw the required data from the database.Here is the code I am using vb.10

```
    `Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection 

    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim tables As DataTableCollection = ds.Tables

    Dim source1 As New BindingSource()

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter        

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

    dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop  \studentmarks.accdb"
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()

    Dim isFirstColumn As Boolean = True
    Dim student As String = ""
    Dim course As String = ""
    Dim grade As String = ""


    Dim x As String = studentList.Text
    Dim y As String = courseList.Text
    Dim z As String = gradeList.Text     


    Dim defaultSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM studentfile "       

    If studentList.SelectedIndex > -1 Then 
        If isFirstColumn Then
            student = "WHERE student = '" & x & "' " 
        Else
            student = "AND student = '" & x & "' "
        End If
        isFirstColumn = False
    End If

    If courseList.SelectedIndex > -1 Then 
        If isFirstColumn Then
            course = "WHERE course = '" & y & "' " 
        Else
            course = "AND course = '" & y & "' "
        End If
        isFirstColumn = False
    End If       

    If gradeList.SelectedIndex > -1 Then 
        If isFirstColumn Then
            grade = "WHERE grade = '" & z & "' " 
        Else
            grade = "AND grade = '" & z & "' "
        End If
        isFirstColumn = False
    End If       

    Dim sql As String = defaultSQL & student & course & grade

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

    da.Fill(ds, "topclass")


    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))

    source1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1

    DataGridView1.Refresh()

    Dim cnt As Integer

    cnt = DataGridView1.Rows.Count

    TextBox1.Text = cnt - 1

    Dim dayclass As String = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox8.Text = dayclass
    con.Close()


End Sub`
```

many thanks
grey

Comment: It would not make sense to multi-select in the list boxes. How would you determine which student went with which course and with which grade?

Comment: Hi Mary,
The idea is that you would select lets say 2 students in the student list and get all of their details up,the rest is down to the dynamic sql code that is created via the program
regards
greycat

Answer (score 0):

Using the .SelectedItems (and a lot of jiggery with the where clause.... you should be able to use this to EITHER have multi-select of single select accross all three listboxes as well as not selecting anything from any of them too...

The only question I would have would be whether you want all the 'AND's as this would mean if you selected two students, you wouldnt get any results... as no two students are the same right? Unless you selected two 'Dave's in which it would return both. For example!

Might suggest changing some for 'OR's or look at what the end result might be? Either way comment and let us know if need any further help

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim tables As DataTableCollection = ds.Tables

    Dim source1 As New BindingSource()

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

    dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop  \studentmarks.accdb"
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()


    Dim student As String = ""
    Dim course As String = ""
    Dim grade As String = ""

    Dim defaultSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM studentfile "
    Dim WhereClause As String = ""
    Dim StudentCourseGrade As String
    'Students---------------------------------------------
    For Each stu In studentList.SelectedItems
        StudentCourseGrade = "(student='" & stu & "'"
        For Each crs In courselist.SelectedItems
            StudentCourseGrade = StudentCourseGrade & " AND course = '" & crs & "'"
            For Each grd In gradeList.SelectedItems
                StudentCourseGrade = StudentCourseGrade & " AND grade = '" & crs & "'"
            Next
        Next
        StudentCourseGrade = StudentCourseGrade & ")"

        If WhereClause.Length = 0 Then
            WhereClause = "WHERE " & StudentCourseGrade
        Else
            WhereClause = " OR " & StudentCourseGrade
        End If
    Next
    'Students---------------------------------------------

    Dim SQL As String = defaultSQL & WhereClause

    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

    da.Fill(ds, "topclass")


    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))

    source1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1

    DataGridView1.Refresh()

    Dim cnt As Integer

    cnt = DataGridView1.Rows.Count

    TextBox1.Text = cnt - 1

    Dim dayclass As String = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox8.Text = dayclass
    con.Close()


End Sub
```

Hth 
Chicken

Comment: hi chicken,thankyou for that,your code is more abbreviated than mine but works in the same way and allows the selection of only one item in the list.What I was looking for is code that would allow the selection of more than one item in the list box.eg if I had 20 names in my studentList,I could highlight more than one name,lets say three and get the details of the three students up in the DGV.I can use the SelectionMode property to enable highlighting more than one item in the ListBox,but the existing code only allows one students details up at a time.any help appreciated

Comment: Hi Grey it will let you select more than one, however, the SQL string will need to be replaced with 'OR's I'll script something now that can maybe show Each Student with a specific Grade? - Ie you select multiple students, but only one grade, the sql would be... `WHERE (student=A AND grade=1) OR (student=B AND grade=1) OR (student=C AND grade=1)` if that make sense? at the moment the code is stating `WHERE (student=A AND grade=1) AND (student=B AND grade=1) AND (student=C AND grade=1)`

Comment: I've updated the answer with a nested `For` if you only select Three students, they should definately come up in the DGV, if you then select a course, it will ONLY show the ones (of the three students you selected) that have that course, if you then select a grade, it will again ONLY show the ones of the three, which have that grade, ON that course :D - Its not impractical to do all of this in VB rather than SQL, but its just a matter of getting your head around the AND's and OR's hth mate!